# how to pass an ip address of another ec2 instance in terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have a setup where I have on ec2 cluster that acts as a client server and another ec2 instance that is running a database. What I want to do is to have the client server to communicate with the database ec2 instance.

```
resource "aws_instance" "db" {
  ami           = "ami-0e38c97339cddf4bd" 
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name = "aws_ec2"
  user_data = file("ec2_setup.sh")
  security_groups = [aws_default_security_group.default_sg.name]
  tags = {
    Name = "database"
  }
  root_block_device {
    tags = {
      Name = "root"
    }
    volume_size = 512
    volume_type = "gp2"
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted = false
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "client" {
  ami           = "ami-0e38c97339cddf4bd" 
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name = "aws_ec2"
  user_data = file("ec2_setup.sh")
  security_groups = [aws_default_security_group.default_sg.name]
  tags = {
    Name = "client-server"
  }
  root_block_device {
    tags = {
      Name = "root"
    }
    volume_size = 32
    volume_type = "gp2"
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted = false
  }
}
```

Is there a way I could pass the internal ip address of the db instance to my client instance so that my app inside in the client instance can access it during runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would attach a [Route53 private hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) to your VPC. And create an internal DNS Record in that zone that points to your database server. Then configure your EC2 instance to resolve the database via that DNS record.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "private_zone" {
  name = "internal"
  vpc {
    vpc_id = <reference to your vpc ID>
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "db" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.private_zone.zone_id
  name    = "db.internal"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "30"
  records = aws_instance.db.private_ip
}
```

Then your client EC2 instance can just use the DNS address `db.internal` to connect to the database server.

The advantage of doing it this way, is that if you need to modify or replace your DB instance in such a way that the IP changes, you don't have to make any updates to your client instance.

Comment: this is such an elegant solution, thank you!